# How to rollback using Datastax driver 3.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have 2 repositories and I want a piece of information to be added in both of them. If the 2nd one fails then I want to roll back the operation in the first repository. Is there a way to do operations atomically in Cassandra in code, not `cql`?

I suppose I could try to delete the entry in the first repository if the operation in 2nd repository fails but I'll prefer a way in which Cassandra does it so that I don't have to maintain the logic in my application

Comment: You have to mention your exact requirement. Are these two entries having same data but it should be having different primary keys in different tabbles? If yes, I suggest Materialised views

Comment: They are two different tables with their own primary keys. Some data is added in table 1 and the part of data is added in table 2 but i want that if insert in table 2 fails then I also delete entry in table 1. So insert in table 1 and table2 should be atomic. I want to know if cassandra java driver provides a way to do atomic operations.

Comment: I suppose I could do this in cql using ‘BATCH’. What is the equivalent of ‘BATCH’ in java driver?

Comment: This will do it I hope https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.0-alpha/manual/core/statements/batch/